# How to bypass captcha when extracting data from website. I am extracting from https://jp.indeed.com/

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup, python-requests, user-agent

When Extracting locally, there is no problem, but when I am using my production website ,there is captcha screen before extraction. I am using Heroku and Django.

```
 header ={ "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 
 Firefox/77.0" }
 r = requests.get(url,headers=header)
 soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
```

But when I print soup variable , I can see that there is a form to solve the captcha . How can I bypass captcha

Comment: Er... don't? To quote indeed's ToS: `Use of any automated system or software, whether operated by a third party or otherwise, to extract data from the Site (such as screen scraping or crawling) is prohibited.` If you want to break that, why should we help you?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to bypass a captcha. That's what captchas are made for, so you can't automate any actions on a webpage.